# How to add a new endpoint to my servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I want to add a new endpoint call say 'getAll', how can I add it ?
say I want a URL to target: www.localhost:8080/Alpha/getAll ?

Do I need to create any annotation ?

```
@WebServlet("/Alpha")
public class Alpha extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Alpha() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Alpha` is a servlet, and only has two endpoint methods `doGet` and `doPost` which are called based on the request you send it (either HTTP GET or HTTP POST). You can't add another endpoint here. You can either use one of the tow endpoint, or create another servlet for your new endpoint or create a Rest API in your application.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, I'd declare a new servlet with an `@WebServlet` annotation.

   @WebServlet("/Alpha")
   public class Alpha extends HttpServlet { 
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      ...
2. No, this would NOT necessarily be available from the URL `http://localhost:8080/Alpha"`'.
3. The first level is your [Context root](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).  This is determined by your Servlet container (here, Tomcat); not anywhere in your Java code, your web.xml, or any possible annotations.

   If your ContextRoot happened to be "/", then yes: `http://localhost:8080/Alpha` would work.  But ordinarily, your endpoint would instead be something like `http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/Alpha`.
4. Here are several examples for setting a context root in the Eclipse IDE.  The specifics may vary from Tomcat, JBoss, WebSphere/Liberty, etc.

[Eclipse – How to change web project context root](https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-how-to-change-web-project-context-root/)